# USB Floppy Drive does not stop running and Windows 7 showes stuff, that should not be on the disc

Tags: windows-7, usb, floppy

My problem is a tough one.

I have a USB Floppy Drive (I can plug my floppy drive via USB into my Computer (Win7)), which should read the floppy discs correctly, but sometimes, wenn I press on that little eject button on the front of the reader/drive and than press in Windows the "remove Hardware safely" feature (or something like that, I can't really remember and I can not reverse the follwing), it spins, trying to read something, maybe, and does not stop. Infact, it even spins faster, at least it sounds louder then it normaly should.

Before that happend: I tried to change the floppy discs, but when I clicked on that drive (A:) again, it (Windows 7) still showed me the files of the old floppy disc, that one, that no longer is inside the reader. Even after doing that "remove Hardware safely" thing. I even think, these tables got swapped, because sometimes I see thoese names change, but when I try to click on one of them, some errors occour (mostly, errors, that indicates, that there is different stuff in these files, than there should be)

I searched for about 2 hours on the Internet, not finding anything..
How can I reverse/fix this?

Thank you in advance and I hope you understand my question correctly.

Comment: usb floppy drives are cheap why don't you try getting another one and trying that?

Comment: I read about this in many other forums, with different problems, but there are reasons, why I can't do that. I am sorry.

Comment: well what would you do if it was an issue with the usb floppy drive itself? and by the way you cant diagnose that for sure unless you have/get another... Next best thing as teset is try plugging it into another computer.. another windows one or preferably even a linux one just to make it very differetnt

Comment: Well that is something I did not think about. But later, I wan't to try Keltari's method. It sounds, like this is exactly what my Computer is doing and why this stuff could happen... Thank you anyways

Comment: It just stopped not working properly... I now can change the floppy discs, whenever I want, without not showing the right files... I can not figure out, what windows did, but if I do, I'll answer my own question here

Answer (score 1):

I am hazarding a guess here.  My first issue is that I dont have a Windows 7 machine.  Secondly, while I *do* have two USB floppy drives (which I cant remember using in the past two decades), I dont actually have any 3.5" floppy disks anymore...

My first thought that the disk's contents were being cached. I plugged in both my floppy drives, but neither had an option to enable or disable the cache in Windows Device Manager.  So I did some googling and found some people with similar problems.  Their solution was to disable ***drive indexing*** on the floppy drive.

You can accomplish this by the following:

- Click Start and in the search box type in Search
- From the menu click on Indexing Options
- Remove the floppy drive from being indexed

Again, this is just a shot in the dark, but worth trying.

Comment: Could a floppy be destroyed, if I put it in the drive now? I have to put one in, otherwise it won't stop running (Just as I said up there... in my question... that drive went loud ...

Comment: @TheArray Its possible. but not likely.  Just reboot the computer so it stops doing whatever it is trying to do.

Comment: Alright: I tried restarting, but it still runs (the floppy drive)... infact, the Computer won't boot... it always shows the BIOS message (were you can press del to go into the Bios, etc...), but pressing buttons, does not do anything... I just pulled the USB out of the Computer.. now it starts like it should (even without restarting or ctrl+alt+del), but putting it back on the Computer makes it run again and sometimes Windows softlocks... I'll just try your solution with indexing... nevertheless thank you

Comment: The good news are: the drive stopped running... I think it needed it's time |-,   ... but the bad news: drive indexing did not work... that drice (Letter A:) was not shown in this menu...it just said "users","internet explorer history","offlinefiles","startmenu" and "windows short notes"... on the button, were you need admin rights, it also shows my C: and a D: drive, but not that A:... I also tried what you tried: The Windows Device Manager Cache deactivation: it did not show anything for me either (no policy tab...)... Thank you; do you have other ideas?

Comment: And I checked my floppy disks, I tested (look in my question-text up there ^), on another Computer (Windows 95; build in floppy drive) and they worked fine again... so yes, it looks like we are on the right way